# python - Error when trying to receive output from check_output

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, sniffing

My code is supposed to track down a packet sniffed with scapy and check which program sent/received the packet, put "Unknown" if the program isn't found

**Code :**

```
source_software = check_output(["netstat", "-nb"], shell = True).decode()
source_software = source_software[source_software.find(str(packet_dictionary["Port"])) : ]
source_software = source_software[source_software.find("\n") + 2 : source_software.find("]")]
if "Can not" not in source_software and len(source_software) > MINIMUM_LENGTH:
    packet_dictionary["Software"] = source_software
else:
    packet_dictionary["Software"] = "Unknown"
```

**Errors :**

```
File "Client.py", line 44, in add_to_list
source_software = check_output(["netstat", "-nb"], shell = True).decode()
File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['netstat', '-nb']' returned non-zero 
exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be python doesn't have permission to run netstat or any else, but you can debug it with the following command

```
source_software = check_output("netstat -nb;  exit 0", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode()
print source_software
```

Comment: I forgot it, I coded this piece of code a few weeks ago and came back into it today, forgot I have to run it as an Administrator

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the bottom line of the exceptions, the problem is that:

```
Command '['netstat', '-nb']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

...which means that is it not about `check_output` itself, rather it is just reporting back that the command you attempted to run using it, failed and exited with code 1.

You may want to run the command in the shell and check if it work as expected.